# List of group id actually used on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, group

How can I get a list of group id which are currently used for Debian OS. I know that e.g. 0-99 are reservered for Debian "intern" things, but I'm wondering which ID is used for which group inside this section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#uid-and-gid-classes), groups in the 0-99 range are reserved and maintained in the [`base-passwd`](https://packages.qa.debian.org/b/base-passwd.html) package; the current list is in [`group.master`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/blob/master/group.master):

```
root:*:0:
daemon:*:1:
bin:*:2:
sys:*:3:
adm:*:4:
tty:*:5:
disk:*:6:
lp:*:7:
mail:*:8:
news:*:9:
uucp:*:10:
man:*:12:
proxy:*:13:
kmem:*:15:
dialout:*:20:
fax:*:21:
voice:*:22:
cdrom:*:24:
floppy:*:25:
tape:*:26:
sudo:*:27:
audio:*:29:
dip:*:30:
www-data:*:33:
backup:*:34:
operator:*:37:
list:*:38:
irc:*:39:
src:*:40:
gnats:*:41:
shadow:*:42:
utmp:*:43:
video:*:44:
sasl:*:45:
plugdev:*:46:
staff:*:50:
games:*:60:
users:*:100:
nogroup:*:65534:
```

Comment: This is the "default" list, installed packages may add additional groups - as does every user account. The list of current groups in a system can be found under `/etc/group`.

Comment: @Dubu Not for groups in the 0-99 range; see the [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.2.2) for details.

Comment: Ah. I overlooked that only those groups were requested, sorry.