# Typically, which file users (owners) come with a distro?

Tags: users, ownership

Typically, after installing a distro we get a root user and a `sudo` user.

I don't know if these are typically the only users owning files (as a `user`/`u` or "owner"), are they? or are there typically more users owning files and if so, what are these?

Comment: After a fresh install, use the command `getent passwd` to view a list of the local users. You can then loop through it with `find` to get a list files and directories that are owned by each uster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically other users owning files; which specifically depends on your distribution and the packages you have installed.

You can find them by running

```
find /usr/bin \! -user root
```

(with other paths too, depending on what files you’re curious about). For example, on Debian-based systems, `/usr/bin/man` is owned by `man`.

More comprehensively, if your system assigns ids starting at 1000 for “real” users,

```
find / \( \! -user root \) -uid -1000
```

will list all files owned by a non-root, system user.

Distributions commonly set up quite a few “system” users; see [List of group id actually used on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209984/86440) for a detailed list of default Debian system users. Additional users can be added by packages. These users don’t necessarily *own* files, they can be used to *run* programs; but any Unix-style system will generally have quite a few files owned by users other than root and actual human users.